# C# Anonymous Type

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

When I say Anonymous Type Declaration

> var someType = new { Name = "Jon
>   Skeet", Age = 10 };

However the Keyword

```
var is  implicitly typed
```

but when i print

```
Response.Write(someType.GetType().Name);
```

it produces `<>f__AnonymousType0`2`.`What is this symbol `<>` relates to?

Comment: Though the type *logically* does not have a name, the metadata format does not permit nameless types, so we just pick an "impossible" name. You'll note that we do the same thing for anonymous *functions*. If you're clever, you can get the method info for an anonymous function and ask its name; you'll get a similar "impossible" name back. We also generate impossible names for closures, special fields of iterator blocks, and so on.

Comment: I hope you are in compiler development team @ Microsoft.Right ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler generates a regular class for your anonymous type and chooses a name that is valid in IL but not in C# to prevent name conflicts with your type names.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the type name. It doesn't mean anything specific, but uses a sequence of characters that is unlikely to conflict with any human-written code.